# modules editing issues

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

In a Joomla website, can I directly edit the default.php file in the modules folder's template folder? Or are those automatically generated while creating the site? Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

Please provide me with concrete images and stories about Joomla instead of repeating what documents say please.

[**UPDATE**] As long as it works, I edit ALL myself. Oh yes, soo good my first obstacle is being clarified.

Comment: nothing is automatically generated when installing Joomla. Once you upload it to the FTP then all the files are where they're supposed to be. As for editing the default.php files, would it not be easier to edit them via the FTP?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make some changes to the files placed in modules/mod_abc/tmpl
(replace mod_abc with your module name)
you need to copy that file to joomla-root/templates/[your-current-template]/html/mod_abc/

then you can edit your file here. This is the standard joomla way to override module template.